# hp mini 110-3510nr laptop won't restart

Tags: laptop, reboot

Here is the information of my hardware and software
hardware : hp mini 110-3510nr
OS : Windows 7 starter (freshly installed)

My laptop is a hp mini 110-3510nr.  It has windows 7 starter installed in it.  The problem is when I click restart on the windows 7, it just shutdown the windows.  After that nothing on the screen, the power is still on, the wireless LAN light is also on.  It just won't restart on its own just like any other laptops.  I have to manually switch the power to off and then press the power again to turn on the computer.  This also happens when I go inside the bios.  When I save changes and exit the bios, the screen is just blank.  Power light and wireless LAN is still on but the screen remains blank.  I have to manually toggle the power off and on again for it to boot to windows again.  Anybody knows what is the problem with my laptop?  I'm guessing this is some kind of motherboard or bios problem maybe?  Any idea or suggestions would be great.

Additional information:  When I press shutdown in Windows 7, it will just shutdown with all the power lights and wireless LAN lights off.  Which is what it is expected to do.  So no problem with the shutdown, only with the restart.

Please help me with this problem.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update : I was able to solve the problem by updating the bios.  Problem solved like a charm.